# can't able to upload 3MB pdf , mp3 file to aws s3

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto

I am getting the below error while uploading 3MB pdf,mp3 file types to aws s3. But i can upload KB size file. am trying to upload using the syntax

```
 uploaded_file = request.FILES['upload_file'].read()
 k.set_contents_from_string(uploaded_file,headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment'})

[Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

**Note: Those things are done in another aws account.**

anyone help me to solve this error

Comment: I think you might need a multipart upload for that. Have a look here: http://codeinpython.blogspot.nl/2015/08/s3-upload-large-files-to-amazon-using.html

Comment: Also this might be helpful too: https://github.com/boto/boto3